# simplest code to check array possible combinations

Tags: javascript, data-structures

What's the simplest, library-free code for implementing get array possible combinations in javascript? I want to write

```
var preDefinedCombinations = [
    ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    ['a', 'c', 'd'],
    ['a'],
    ['b'],
    ['c']
];
var selectedvalues = ['a', 'b', 'd'];
getPossbileCombination(selectedvalues, preDefinedCombinations);
```

and get

```
 ['a','b','c'],['a','c','d']
```

I tried below code but does'nt work as expected, it always give me missing term in case user select 'a', 'b' than alert shows him to select 'c' for valid combination. But if user selects 'a', 'b' & ['d'] it does'nt give possible combination for selected values.

```
var preDefinedCombinations = [['a','b','c'], ['a','c','d'], ['a'], ['b'], ['c']];
var selectedvalues = ['a','b','d'];

function selectOption(value){
   var checkIndex = selectedvalues.indexof(value);
   if(checkIndex == -1){
       selectedvalues.push(value);
   }else{
       selectedvalues.splice(checkIndex, -1);
   }

}

function intersect_safe(a, b)
{
 var ai=0, bi=0;
 var result = new Array();

 while( ai < a.length && bi < b.length )
 {
    if      (a[ai] < b[bi] ){ ai++; }
    else if (a[ai] > b[bi] ){ bi++; }
    else /* they're equal */
    {
      result.push(a[ai]);
      ai++;
      bi++;
    }
 }

 return result;
}

function checkVaildCombination(){
   if(preDefinedCombinations.indexOf(selectedvalues) == -1){
       var missing_bits = [];
       for (var i = 0; i < preDefinedCombinations.length; i++) {
           var missing_bit = intersect_safe(preDefinedCombinations[i], selectedvalues);
           if (missing_bit.length == selectedvalues.length) { // candidate for valid answer
               missing_bit = [];
               for (var j = 0; j < preDefinedCombinations[i].length; j++) {
                   if (selectedvalues.indexOf(preDefinedCombinations[i][j]) == -1) { // actual missing bit
                       missing_bit.push(preDefinedCombinations[i][j]);
                   }
               }

               missing_bits.push(missing_bit);
           }
       }

       alert('Invalid Combination, if you select any of these you`ll get a valid combination:\n' + missing_bits.toString());
   }else{
       alert('Valid Combination');
   }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: @thefourtheye it is clear from code point of view that he needs all possible values to fetch from pre defined combination using a custom function. He already given a example that if he pass array ['a','b','d'] than function will return all possible values as per selected values. He needs logic for getPossbileCombination function

Comment: @RajendraKhabiya: Yes. But the relevant part, how the selection should be made, is missing. Also, I don't see any displayed effort of his/her own solutions.

Comment: Please explain why your expected result is the way it is. Is only one mismatch allowed? Must the result be the same length? Are many mismatches allowed? Must matches be in the same order? If many mismatches allowed can all the values mismatch (for example `['a','b','c']` is allowed to mach `['w','t','f']`)?

Comment: Also explain why `['a','b','d']` does not match `['a']`

Comment: @slebetman when user select ['a', 'b','d'] it sounds logically that they tried to make a combination of three terms and not a single selection. If you think we have to show 'a' as well than please help with code that gives ['a'] as well. thanks !

Comment: @Wolph I think he tried some bit of function and it shows his/her effort to found solution. I think we have to help him if you guys know the solution. i tried to solve this but don't got appropriate solution. Thanks

Comment: It's not clear at all from your example what your inputs are and what the desired outputs are. Please clarify.